# How to keep mutalisks moving?

Tags: starcraft-2

TeamLiquid wiki (http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Mutalisk) tells:

> Due to their relatively slow acceleration, Mutalisks should be continually moved at full speed even when there is no harm in sight - this allows them to easily escape at full speed when defenders arrive.

How to do that?

I understand, you need to click continuosly "somewhere" to keep them "flying/moving", not only "flying/standing". But once you click any target they will shoot and stop. Isn't it? Or, immediately after 'shoot' command you need to stack another command "move away" with 'Shift'-click? Or without shift click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it said in [liqupedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Mutalisk)

> Like all units without firing
>   animations, Mutalisks can attack while
>   remaining at full movement speed, if
>   issued the attack command followed
>   instantly by the move command.

So, press `A-left click-right click` at ground (not unit). If attack cooldown is not elapsed then mutalisks will continue to move futher. Otherwise they attack and continue to move at full speed.

Answer (score 7):

What their slow acceleration refers to is the time it takes them to reach top speed.  When stopping to fight, there is no way to keep them at top speed.  They will stop, shoot and when you issue another move command they will slowly build to top speed.  You can abuse this a little by micro.  As long as you don't let your mutalisks reach a full stop it should cut down on their acceleration, this can be accomplished like a 'scoot and shoot' marine micro with attack followed by move commands.

This concept however is bigger in muta placement then muta micro, here is an example when you should be aware of this:

You have a flock of mutalisks that you intend to attack the mineral line with.  You can sit just out of LOS while you prepare your attack and then attempt to fly in to hit the mineral line.  But because they take a long time to accelerate, your opponent will have a better chance of reacting and defending your attack.

However, if instead of staying just out of LOS you keep your mutalisks even farther away, your mutalisks will have a 'running start' and enter your opponents base at full speed.

Comment: Mutalisks *must* come to a complete stop before attacking.  Unlike Marines (which have instant deceleration), Muta deceleration requires time.  Additionally, once they have fired, Mutalisks will have to accelerate again to achieve top speed.  This means trying to stutter step with Mutalisks is much slower than Marines (relatively speaking).  Coming from Broodwars (which many people did), this will feel like Muta micro is impossible.

Comment: That is not completely true. Just tried this in unit test map and it is indeed possible to fire them without coming to a full stop!

Comment: Tzenes, seems like you have an answer, not a comment. Would you mind to create an answer? So I will be able to accept it as a solution? Though, Cray is not agree with you ... I will double check also...

Comment: @budda apparently my post didn't catch what I was getting at.  Mutalisk acceleration has such a small affect on attack micro that it isn't worth dealing with. I think tzenes caught this. While potentially possible, it isn't valuable.  There are two important things to consider with mutalisk acceleration: first is be aware that fleeing after an attack will be more difficult due to the required time to accelerate (whether the mutalisks fully stop or not doesn't matter). Provide your mutalisks extra escape time. Second, that you can approach a base at full speed by getting a running start

Comment: @Cray I mispoke, they *must* come to a complete stop *when* attacking.  It does not necessarily happen that the stop comes first, but it *must* happen.  You cannot shoot and move in SC2 with Muta

Answer (score 1):

One method is to [patrol-move](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Hotkeys#Patrol) the Mutalisks in a circle, for example. This will keep the Mutas at their maximum speed. However, the Mutas will still stop and attack if an enemy comes into range. But with quick enough reflexes it should be possible to command at least some of the Mutas to move away without losing any speed.

Comment: Is that for 'staging' your mutalisks or for attacking?  Once the mutalisk gets agro of an enemy it will stop and attack... I like the idea of using it to keep your idle mutalisks moving though

Comment: @Aardvark I was mainly thinking about holding a position. Maintaining top speed means that (some) mutas are more likely to be able to evade an attacker. It also means that, as alluded to in your answer, the mutas will reach the attacker slightly earlier if you want to fight back.